# iPhone Navigation Bar Images

Tags: iphone

I'd like to replace the back button and the entire navigation bar in my iPhone app with custom images.  First of all, is this possible?  Second, if so, how?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean custom images for just the buttons on the nav bar, or the entire nav bar itself (background, etc)?

Comment: I'd be interested for buttons too actually =)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This code will modify every UINavigationBar in your app.

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"MyNavigationBar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

Comment: @pierre good answer, you should ask a call to super just in case you want to keep the back buttons for example.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to override the look and feel of Apple's navigation bar easily, and even if you are able to, there's a good chance it will go against their policy of avoiding private API's.  However, it is pretty simple to create your own look-alike navigation bar using all custom images.  This would work well for simple one-off screens that need the navigation bar, but will be a beast to implement on a complex UINavigationController-based hierarchy.

Edit: It looks like people have been able to change the background by overriding the `-drawRect` selector: [Custom background for UINavigationBar?](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=7951074) .  I don't see any reports of whether or not the changes were approved for the App Store.

Comment: I witnessed many applications that involve such practice getting approved for sale in the store. Apple does not care.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to change navigation bar image and tab bar image to your custom images:

```
   if([[UINavigationBar class] respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)])  {//iOS >=5.0
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myCustomImage.png"];

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [image drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];


    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar   setBackgroundImage:newImage  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:newImage forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:newImage];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];
}
```